# Are There Any Benefits/Drawbacks to the Different Movement Types Besides Speed?

Tags: ufo-afterlight

Once you research the necessary Science and train your soldiers with the correct military skills, they gain the ability to perform a variety of different stances, both while moving and while stationary.  The new abilities are as follows:

**Stationary Abilities**

- Lie Prone
- Crouch
- Stand (Default)

**Movement Abilities (Slowest to Fastest)**

- Crawl
- Walk (Default)
- Run

---

Aside from the obvious changes in movement speed when running or crawling, are they any other bonuses/detriments given by using these abilities?  If not, it seems like 'walk' is a pretty useless form of movement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, they change

- reaction times
- visibility to enemy
- shooting accuracy

i.e. it takes more time from running to shooting than from walking to shooting

modifiers are added to any action performed in that stance.

cannot find the value for readying the weapon, but you can time that fairly easily in the game shooting at ground.

```
  1 standing
  - speed modifier  0
  - visibility modifier?  0.2
  - range of view modifier?  1.2
  - angle of view modifier?  1.5
  - doesn't require training yes
  - works without special equipement yes
  - accuracy modifier  1
  - size modifier  1

 2 walking
  - speed modifier  2
  - visibility modifier?  1
  - range of view modifier?  1
  - angle of view modifier?  1
  - doesn't require training yes
  - works without special equipement yes
  - accuracy modifier  1
  - size modifier  1

3 running
 - speed modifier  3
 - visibility modifier?  1.5
 - range of view modifier?  0.75
 - angle of view modifier?  0.5
 - doesn't require training no
 - works without special equipement no
 - accuracy modifier  1
 - size modifier  1

4 kneeling
 -  speed modifier  0
 -  visibility modifier?  0.1
 - range of view modifier?  1.2
 - angle of view modifier?  1
 - doesn't require training no
 - works without special equipement no
 - accuracy modifier  1.25
 - size modifier  0.75

5  laying
 - speed modifier  0
 - visibility modifier?  0.1
 - range of view modifier?  1.2
 - angle of view modifier?  1
 - doesn't require training no
 - works without special equipement no
 - accuracy modifier  1.6
 - size modifier  0.75

6 crowling
 - speed modifier  0.4
 - visibility modifier?  0.25
 - range of view modifier?  1.2
 - angle of view modifier?  1
 - doesn't require training no
 - works without special equipement no
 - accuracy modifier  1
 - size modifier  0.75
```

question mark for where I am guessing the in-game effect

size modifier changes also how cover hide you and how 'tall' you are in visibility checks (terrain line of sight matters)

Comment: Can you explain how each one affects those three items, specifically?  Thanks!

Comment: it also affects your soldiers ability to detect enemies

Comment: Oh, neat.  Out of curiosity, where did you find this information?